# What does [a-z0-9] mean?

Tags: regex

I Have a Question. I'm just learning regular expressions in a python class and I do not understand what [a-z0-9] means. Can someone explain what each part means? I was on Google but I only confused myself.

Comment: It means a character in the range between a-z or 0-9.

Comment: Why the negative vote. Lately I am feeling that stackoverflow is getting too much hostile to newbies asking simple qustions. There are resources to learn Regex, but a newbie might need our help for correct direction!

Comment: @MangatRaiModi, teaching utterly entry-level basics better covered by tutorial-level documentation is not what SO is for! Even when the site was first announced in 2008, it was described as a resource by and for **programmers** -- not people who want to be programmers but aren't yet.

Comment: Not sure regex is an entry level basic...

Answer (score 5):

In a regular expression, if you have [a-z] then it matches any lowercase letter. [0-9] matches any digit. So if you have [a-z0-9], then it matches any lowercase letter or digit.

You can refer to the Python documentation for more information, especially in the [chapter 6.2-Regular Expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: It's a **buggy** way of doing that, though, since collation order isn't the same for all languages.

Comment: Some languages use `AaBbCcDd...` instead of `ABCD...abcd...`, for instance; in that case, `[a-z]` can include a subset of upper-case characters as well.

Comment: It's much safer if you're going to be used in a wide range of locations to use `[[:lower:]]` for lower-case characters, and `[[:upper:]]` for upper-case ones; that way it works no matter what the collation order is, or if your current language has letters before `a` or after `z`. Similarly, `[[:digit:]]` is the preferred alternative to `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

It matches from a to z and 0 to 9,just one of it.

Comment: Thanks for this easy-to-understand explanation!